# creating a java method find fee CD class

Tags: java

I have created a java program that allows CD to be borrowed from a collection, however i now need to create a method find fee (), which applies 10p charge for cds borrowed 1-20 times, 20p charge for cds borrowed 21-30 times, 5% of purchase cost charged for cds borrowed more than 30 times, my attempted code so far :

```
public void borrow(String personBorrowed)
    {
    person = personBorrowed;
    inStock = false;
    timesBorrowed = timesBorrowed + 1;
    }
    public void main(String[] args) 
    { if (timesborrowed >= 1-19) { cost = '+10p'; } 
    else if (timesborrowed >= 1-29) { cost = '20p'; } 
    else if (timesborrowed >= 30) { cost = '+ 10.00/5= 2.00'; } 
    System.out.println("Cost = " + cost); } }
```

(above code is from the bottom line)

my code:

```
public class CD
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private String title;
    private String artist;
    private int noOfTracks;
    private double cost;
    private boolean inStock;
    private String person;
    private int timesBorrowed;
    private boolean returnCD;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class CD
     */
    public CD(String newTitle, String newArtist,int newNoOfTracks,double newCost)
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        title = newTitle;
        artist = newArtist;
        noOfTracks = newNoOfTracks;
        cost = newCost;
        inStock = true;
        person = null;
        timesBorrowed = 0;
    }


     /**
     * Default Constructor for Testing
     */
    public CD()
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        title = "Blue Print";
        artist = "Jay Z";
        noOfTracks = 15;
        cost = 10.00;
        inStock = true;
        person = null;
        timesBorrowed = 0;
    }



    /**
     * An example of a method - replace this comment with your own
     */

    public String getTitle()
    {
    return title;
    }


    /**
     * An example of a method - replace this comment with your own
     */

    public String getArtist()
    {
    return artist;
    }


    /**
     * An example of a method - replace this comment with your own
     */

    public int getNoOfTracks()
    {
    return noOfTracks;
    }


    /**
     * An example of a method - replace this comment with your own
     */

    public double getCost()
    {
    return cost;
    }


    /**
     * An example of a method - replace this comment with your own
     */

    public void printDetails()
    {
    System.out.println("Title: " + title);
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println("Artist: " + artist);
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println("Number of Tracks: " + noOfTracks);
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println("Cost: " + cost);
    }


    /**
     * An example of a method - replace this comment with your own
     */ 

    public void borrow(String personBorrowed)
    {
    person = personBorrowed;
    inStock = false;
    timesBorrowed = timesBorrowed + 1;
    }
    public void main(String[] args) 
    { if (timesborrowed >= 1-19) { cost = '+10p'; } 
    else if (timesborrowed >= 1-29) { cost = '20p'; } 
    else if (timesborrowed >= 30) { cost = '+ 10.00/5= 2.00'; } 
    System.out.println("Cost = " + cost); } } 
}
```

any answers or replies and help would be greatly appreciated as I really confused and cant figure this out.

Comment: Think about this: A compiler is a program that takes things literally. How would you remotely expect it to understand that `+10p` means add 10 pence when in quotes like that? And how it should expect to parse invalid logic of `foo >= 1-19` not as `foo?=-18` but as `foo` is between 1 and 19?

Answer (score 2):

The following makes no sense:

```
 { if (timesborrowed >= 1-19) { cost = '+10p'; } 
    else if (timesborrowed >= 1-29) { cost = '20p'; } 
    else if (timesborrowed >= 30) { cost = '+ 10.00/5= 2.00'; }
```

Use:

```
if(timesborrowed<20) {cost+=0.10;}
else if (timesborrowed <30) {cost +=-.20;}
else {cost +=2;}
```

I'm assuming by `p` you mean pennies or pence, therefore 1/100 of a denomination,

Comment: managed to get it to compile with no syntax errors, thanks guys, help much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

```
(timesborrowed >= 1-19)  This is actually saying if timesborrowed is >= -18
(timesborrowed >= 1-29)  This is actually saying if timesborrowed is >= -28
```

Do this instead

```
 if (timesborrowed < 20)
 eiseif (timesborrowed < 30)  
 else
```

Comment: oops, didnt realise it would give a minus outcome lol, thank you

Comment: You should accept an answer if one helped.